# Finding $P(X+Z>Y)$ where $X,Y,Z$ are exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$,$Y$,$Z$ be independent random variables with exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda$, then $X,Y,Z$ ~ $\xi(\lambda)$.
The task is to calculate $P(X+Z>Y)$.

Comment:
In previous excersices, by finding the joint density function of $X,Y$ ($f_{XY}=\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}1_{[0,+\infty)x[0,+\infty)}(x,y)$) and integrating I got $P(X>Y)=\frac{1}{2}$ but I can't add $Z$ into the mix.

Edit: just in case, I removed what should be the answer.

Comment: As you said, $P(X > Y) = 1/2$, so how is it possible that $P(X+Z > Y)$ also $ = 1/2$?  What you want to prove is false.  (In fact I think the answer is $P(X+Z > Y) = 3/4$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the same principle, you must triple integrate over the domain $\{(x,z,y):x\in[0{..}\infty), z\in[0{..}\infty),y\in[0{..}x+z)\}$

$$\mathsf P(X+Z>Y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^{x+z} \lambda^3\mathrm e^{-\lambda(x+y+z)}~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d z~\mathrm d x $$

Comment: I guess it should be $Y \in (0,x+z)$ but thanks! Just one question you get $f_{X,Y,Z}=f_{X}*f_{Y}*f_{Z}$ just by saying $X,Y,Z$ independent? Do you know where can i find the proof?

Comment: Opps. Yes.  Sorry.  Also $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)\cdot f_Z(z)$ by *definition* of independence.